Llama 3 8B parameters does not show a response
I am using HuggingFace's Llama-3-8B parameter model, so it is running locally and i asked it the question
pipeline("What is the capital of France? Answer in one word.")

And I left it to run for 30 mins, no response.
Even on a Ryzen 7 5800, it does not work. I understand GPU is better, but why does it take this long. I tried using Google-Gemma-2B, and this gives out a HORRIBLE answer, but at least in 1 minute run time.
Any idea why llama takes so long and 50% CPU?

How much memory do you have? Which model specifically (i.e. quantization settings) do you use? does it use 50% of a single core? do you see I/O?

Could you show us the rest of your code? Are you using the base models or the instruction models? Are you sure, that the code is applying the chat template correctly?
